# I am struggling in getting api any function

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I am calling this function:

```
Route::get('/person', function (){
 $person=[

   'first_name'=>'dildar',
   'last_name'=>'Muhammad',

 ];
 return $person;
});
```

and  I browse `https://astrolabe.ml/api/person` but I got error not found page 404

[image]

it does work on new laravel project but I did not found any clue from that why it does not my work.

Comment: put a `dd($person)` instead of `return $person;` and see whether it get data or not.

Comment: are you sure you put the route in api.php? or is it web.php?

Comment: test API's using postman..

Comment: i used postman an also tried as $person but not work

Answer (score 0):

*emphasized text*try to replace this

```
Route::get('/person', function (){
```

to

```
Route::get('person', function (){
```

**Edit:**
remove everything and try this:

```
Route::get('test', 'HomeController@index');
```

HomeController.php

```
public function index(){
dd('x');
}
```

then run:

```
php artisan optimize
```

finally go to `www.example.com/api/test`

Comment: Sir, I do dd("print something ") in api.php file and remove all thing not work at that level   like if there I use https://astrolabe.ml/routes/api.php gives me the same error

Comment: See the edited answer, just don't put any function in api.php, mostly your problem in cache

Comment: did not exactly did the same as you have given... actually API any route gives the same page not found an error

Comment: I am totally stuck almost 3 days sir

Comment: i have created the home controller which wer not already and put the function in that and in api file commented all other stuff and put this route Route::get('test', 'HomeController@index');
and also runt he command ...   but get the same error  ..an also i tried api list to see but that not shows anything of api routeno api route is even shown

Comment: Did you try to remove the cache? php artisan route:cache

Answer (score 0):

Update your code

```
Route::get('/person', function (){
 $person=[

   'first_name'=>'dildar',
   'last_name'=>'Muhammad',

 ];
 return response()->json($person); // Update this thing
});
```

Comment: for the one who vote down, leave the comment here of your reason